# http://localhost/GS doesn't work on the browser of Android Emulator

Tags: android, browser, sencha-touch-2

i follow official documentation of Sencha touch at this link http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started ,i downloaded Sencha Touch 2 SDK and   SDK Tools, i have generate app GS ../GS command and it works fine.then i taped  http:/localhost/GS/ in the Browser of Android emulator but it shows error.it does not display default sencha app. Can anyone tel me why? is there another solution? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find your local ip of the pc you're working on - go to the command line and type 'ipconfig' to get this.

use your local ip for your android device to connect to your localhost.

ex: 192.168.1.x/GS .. instead of the "localhost"

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try 10.0.2.2/GS/ on your Android emulator.